# After WordPress migration only home page loads everything else returns a 404

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, http-status-code-404, digital-ocean

Getting started with a droplet on Digital Ocean, so far it's been a fun process. Now I want to begin migrating my site, so I set everything up and created an `index.php` to where to my root dir as a "construction" page for now. I'm setting up WordPress in a sub-dir and moved all of the contents via `all-in-one WP Migration` which has always worked perfectly for me.

I've given every dir and file inside of `root/public_html` (WordPress installation) `rwx` and atm ownership has been changed to `www-data`. So I got to loadup my site which atm would be something like `<ip address>/public_html` and I log in and I am propmted with the `wp-admin` screen. Everything is working, media files are uploaded, theme is there etc.

When I go to my home page, all the images load but I immediately notice the admin bar at the top, the wp-glyphs aren't loading and I'm getting those weird squares when your computer/phone doesn't know what it's trying to look at. Also any front-end page other than my home returns a 404. My homepage again is accessed by `<ip address>/public_html` so you would think my `about` page would be `<ip address>/public_html/about`, which is where WordPress is sending me to when clicked, but I receive a 404.

I've spent probably 4-5 hours now trying to figure this out and eventually turned to a guide [that walks you through it](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-step-by-step/) but nada so far.

Can anyone offer a suggestion?

### EDIT

I'd like to add that I followed WordPress's instructions on modifying the .htaccess file. I'm assuming it goes in the subdirectory correct?

### `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public_html/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /public_html/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a reference for myself and anyone who might stumble upon this.

### Solution

The answer was that apache was not configured correctly to read `.htaccess` files. If you are experiencing the same problems and have set up your own VPS, go to `apache.conf`, `etc/apache2/apache.conf` and find the correct `<Directory></Directory>` directive that corresponds with your website directory. Inside you should see an option that reads `AllowOverride None`. Change this to `AllowOverride All`.

If this is not the solution for you, at least it's another step out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access wp-admin

If yes then go to dashboard->setting->permalinks 
and update the permalink and the problem solved

Comment: What would I update them to? My live site's permalink structure is https://<domain-name>.com/2018/03/17/sample-post/ and my new one is http://<ip-address>/public_html/2018/03/17/sample-post/. It's following the same structure but with an added directory which is where WordPress is installed.

Answer (score -1):

Access your dashboard by logging in wp-admin then access settings then permanent links, Change them to any of the provided styles save the change it again to your preferred one. This will work well.